# How to access a method of a form from another class ensuring it is the same Form instance - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, class, datagridview, static

**Updated to be more clear....**

I have a main form, `Form1`, and an additional class, `AslLib`. `Form1` contains a method that updates a `dataGridView` control it contains. A method in `AslLib` calls this method.

My problem is that the only way I can make `AslLib` call `Form1`'s method is by creating an instance of `Form1` in `AslLib`'s calling method like so:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void updateDataGUI(int row, string url, string status, long time)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(status);
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in dataGridView1.Rows) dgvr.Cells[0].Value = status;
    }

}



static class AslLib
{
    public static async void makeRequest(string url, int row )
    {
        string result;
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch(); sw.Start();

        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
                response = await client.GetAsync(url);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    result = ((int)response.StatusCode).ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    result = ((int)response.StatusCode).ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException hre)
        {
            result = "Server unreachable";
        }

        sw.Stop();
        long time = sw.ElapsedTicks / (Stopwatch.Frequency / (1000L * 1000L));


        _form.updateDataGUI(row, url, result, time);

    }
}
```

I have tried passing parameters in both the constructor and the method, but because (*i think*) the `makeRequest` method is static, the compiler is giving errors:

```
AsyncURLChecker.AslLib._form: cannot declare instance members in a static class              AsyncURLChecker
Static classes cannot have instance constructors                AsyncURLChecker
```

The result of the above is that the `Console.WriteLine(status);` part of `Form1`'s method correctly outputs `status`, but the `dataGridView` does not change.

My belief is that because I am creating a new instance of `Form1`, I am no longer referencing the original `Form1` containing my `dataGridView`, rather an entirely new copy, so it is not changing.

Can anyone tell me how I might manipulate the original Form1's `dataGridView` from another class? My preferred method would be to call a `Form1` method that updates `dataGridView` rather than directly accessing `dataGridGiew` from `AslLib` if possible.

Comment: Very first task: rename your classes to give them sensible names. `Class1` conveys almost *no* information. Second task: consider whether you should pass the form reference to the `Class1` constructor, or whether it should be a parameter in the method... we don't have nearly enough information to guide you on that.

Comment: I think you want to pass a parameter of type `Form1` to `Class1`'s method. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming). Can you give `Class1` a logical name? Are you trying to follow an OO methodology?

Comment: Thanks, they were for illustration purposes only. Have updated.

Comment: You probably don't wan't your `HttpRequestClass` to directly update a paticular control on a form. Perhaps `MainForm` should be calling a function on `HttpRequestClass`, then using the return value to update the control.

Comment: When I see a class that calls a method on a form I always feel that there is something wrong. Unless your class instance is totally dependant from an existing form (and thus you force the class constructor to receive the form instance) then you should explore the feasibility to have a delegate inside the class called when needed

Comment: @JonSkeet I should have mentioned that the Class's method is static and this seems to be causing issues. Have tried passing Form reference in both constructor and as method parameter. Have updated question to reflect.

Comment: @RodgersandHammertime: You also didn't mention that it was async and returned void... could you not make it *return* the results, and let the form await them?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, like that idea, will give it a whirl...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass reference to existing form instead of creating new one:

```
// on Form1
Class1 c1 = new Class1();
c1.DoSomething(this);

// Class1
public void DoSomething(Form1 form)
{
    form.updateDataGUI(row, url, result, time);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I should mention that DoSomething is a static method and this seems to be causing issues. Might you know How i'd get around this?

Comment: @RodgersandHammertime sorry, was AFK. With static method simply call method without instantiating Calss1: `Class1.DoSomething(this)`

Answer (score 2):

Pass the form into the class constructor

```
private Form1 _form;
public Class1(Form1 form)
{
    _form = form;
}
```

you now have access to the form from within your class.

Comment: Thanks, I have done this, however forgot to mention my Class1 method is static so compiler says static classes cannot have instance constructors?

Comment: change it from static, or pass the form in as method parameter as @lazyberezovsky has suggested. or expose a static property in the static class (test for null before using the form reference)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the original created instance of the `MainForm`. Here is one way you can access it:

```
Application.OpenForms.OfType<MainForm>().First().updateDataGUI(row, url, result, time);
```

([`Application.OpenForms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) contains all the open forms of the currently running application.)

But it is better to redesign your class structure in such a way that you can pass the reference of the `MainForm` object to the class. Another option is to hold the instance in a static property of the `MainForm` itself (if you are sure that only one instance exists at any time).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this.

```
MainForm f = (MainForm)this.Owner;
f.updateDataGUI(row, url, result, time);
```